# How can I use Excel to parse Google Analytics UTM URLs

Tags: microsoft-excel, url, google-analytics

How could I take a URL such as...

website url/directory/another-directory?utm_id=inc0000000&utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=2021+q3+campaign&utm_content=post&utm_adsize=1200x628&utm_audience=general&utm_product=loan+product&promocode=250offer

and parse it down across multiple cells in a row?

[image]

Comment: you could using FIND LEN RIGHT LEFT and MID

Comment: OK... But, how do I do it? I can only do the very basics in Excel.

Comment: You could try to use the menu item Get Data. It should take you through a wizard and suggest parsing of the data...

Comment: Did the URL existed in Excel, or you wanted to get the URL from Website or others automatically?

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach is to find ways to strip out pieces of the string by finding starting points and ending points.

**IF** your string had a regular separator dividing the information of interest, you could use a neat trick using `FILTERXML()` and use it to easily pick each piece out for your output cells. However, this is not the case for your data.

So, somewhat harder. Not to understand, just a bunch to do since you want 11 pieces of data from the string.

I have altered your given string to replace your "website url" with the "ht tps://www.mysite.com" you show in your desired output giving this string that I used in the following material:

**ht tps://www.mysite.com/directory/another-directory?utm_id=inc0000000&utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=2021+q3+campaign&utm_content=post&utm_adsize=1200x628&utm_audience=general&utm_product=loan+product&promocode=250offer**

(Pretend both uses of "ht tps" are really "https"... this editor shows errors if I use them correctly.)

First bit is pretty easy. You know the starting point. It is character 1. So you can use the easier to understand `LEFT()` function. Easier to understand because it isn't too complicated writing the part that finds the stopping point.

(Strictly speaking, it finds the length of string to take out, but that's a stopping point too, so it fits the language I'm describing your approach in. But it's important to know that it's actually a length you will calculate.)

So, how to tell Excel "Stop HERE"? You need to locate something unique enough in the string but still CLOSE (it gets a lot harder to figure the further away it is) to the stopping point you want. Fortunately, there is a "/" after ".com" that you can use. There's a function called `FIND()` that will locate its position. But there's a problem:  there are two of them BEFORE the end of the string. Don't want Excel to pick one of them! But `FIND()` also lets you tell Excel where to start looking so you can tell it "Look in A1 for a "/" but start looking at character 10" so it will never notice those first two.

So then, your formula for the first bit would be:

```
=LEFT(A1,  FIND("/",A1,  FIND("//",A1)+2) - 1)
```

Excel finds the "/" (position 23). You want the character before that to be the end, so you subtract 1 from that. So Excel ends up starting with character 1 and using all characters up to 22. Notice that if the website name had been longer or shorter, Excel wouldn't be slowed down as you are not using its name directly, just things around it.

The next nine bits follow the same idea:  find a starting point and an ending point by using bits of the string before and after the desired data. You will use the `MID()` function for these. It needs to know where to look, where to start, and how far to go after it starts. These formulas assume the datum is in cell A1, so that's done. Finding something that you can use before and after then depends completely on the exact stuff in the string. Notice that the formulas work for the string you give in the question, but if every string has different dividers, they will not work for the different ones.

So, for the rest of the directory structure datum, use:

```
=MID(A1,  FIND("/", A1, FIND("//", A1)+2),  FIND("?",A1) - FIND("/", A1, 
FIND("//", A1)+2) - 1)
```

The part right after A1 is the starting position. It finds that FIRST single "/" found for the website URL in exactly the same way it found it there. It finds how many characters to read before stopping by looking for the "?" that comes after the directory material. But you don't want that actual number. You need to subtract 1 from it since it is one character past the correct end AND you need to subtract off all the characters that come before the starting point. That's what the second `FIND()` in that last part gives you (just like it helped in the second part to find the starting point) and you can see 1 is subtracted after that.

The last eight of those nine bits use the same kind of idea, but the have the handy pieces of string like "utm_source=" to use since they are not duplicated and occur exactly before and after each piece. You COULD use shorter pieces of them, but I prefer to use the whole things as they are easy to choose that way, have the "odd" "utm_" and "=" in them so they are unlikely to occur in the material you desire to extract (which would ruin their use), and it just seems clearer why to choose them if one chooses the whole thing. So they look like this:

```
=MID(A1,  FIND("utm_id=",A1) + LEN("utm_id="),  FIND("utm_source=",A1) - (FIND("utm_id=",A1) + LEN("utm_id=")) - 1)
```

The first one finds "utm_id" and uses it four times. The first two find its starting point, then add its length to that to find the desired string's starting point. Then one finds the start of the following "utm_" string (and subtracts 1) to find the end position, then uses the "utm_id" the last two times to subtract off the beginning length. So you've isolated the "inc0000000" bit.

You can open the formula editor line (above the cells) and highlight, then copy the formula, and go on to the next seven cells, open the formula editor ("F2") and paste them. Then they just need edited for exact strings to search for. (If you use $A$1 instead of A1 in the formulas — as you really should (I was just answering the question, not building a spreadsheet) — you can just copy the whole cell, like you may have done before, and paste that in the seven cells. That's a bit easier...

Anyway, you have the same formula now in all eight cells. Go through the seven you pasted in and replace the "utm_something" strings in the formulas until you have edited all seven and they have their own unique pairs. Definitely copy the exact string right from the big string so you have no typos.

When done, you'll have:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("utm_source=",A1)+LEN("utm_source="),FIND("utm_medium=",A1)-(FIND("utm_source=",A1)+LEN("utm_source="))-1)

=MID(A1,FIND("utm_medium=",A1)+LEN("utm_medium="),FIND("utm_campaign=",A1)-(FIND("utm_medium=",A1)+LEN("utm_medium="))-1)

=MID(A1,FIND("utm_campaign=",A1)+LEN("utm_campaign="),FIND("utm_content=",A1)-(FIND("utm_campaign=",A1)+LEN("utm_campaign="))-1)

=MID(A1,FIND("utm_content=",A1)+LEN("utm_content="),FIND("utm_adsize=",A1)-(FIND("utm_content=",A1)+LEN("utm_content="))-1)

=MID(A1,FIND("utm_adsize=",A1)+LEN("utm_adsize="),FIND("utm_audience=",A1)-(FIND("utm_adsize=",A1)+LEN("utm_adsize="))-1)

=MID(A1,FIND("utm_audience=",A1)+LEN("utm_audience="),FIND("utm_product=",A1)-(FIND("utm_audience=",A1)+LEN("utm_audience="))-1)

=MID(A1,FIND("utm_product=",A1)+LEN("utm_product="),FIND("promocode=",A1)-(FIND("utm_product=",A1)+LEN("utm_product="))-1)
```

The final one is something like the first one except you are looking for the RIGHT end of the string this time. The last piece you want is the actual end of the string, so you only need to figure the starting point and length:

```
=RIGHT(A1,  LEN(A1) - (FIND("promocode=",A1) + LEN("promocode=") - 1))
```

Well, you know how to find "promocode=" since you found it for the 10th cell. If you find that here, you can subtract it (minus 1 from it since its calculation will give you the position right before your actual starting position) from the the whole string's length to get the length of character's you want Excel to read from the END of the string.

This is how you approach ALL such things. If your strings are well-behaved (say you have 10,000 of these and ALL of them have those same "utm_something" strings inside them), it's "as easy as this." This is a bunch of work, but think of it honestly:  once you saw how to do it, it was just a bunch of typing and mousing, not a bunch of thinking and doing a million different things. Just gruntwork, monkey work.

Remember there is the `FILTERXML()` trick I mentioned at the start if the string is even more predictable. Well, completely predictable in using the same divider ("delimiter") in all positions. Then it's super easy.

One can actually take some other approaches, but they are much harder to work with. And... finicky.

When you learn how to use the `LET()` function, you can make those formulas above look much easier to read. AND easier to edit for the different pieces of information.

Good luck with Excel! It's a great tool. Hope you have good experiences with it!